# Function and Argument description not appearing in Excel

Tags: c#, excel-dna

Trying to write an Excel Function to be used, but the description and necessary parameters for the function are not appearing in Excel.  This makes the function kind of useless, as user won't know how to use it.

Tried using ExcelDna.IntelliSense as suggested in other questions, but it is either not working, or I do not have it set up properly.  This is my first time using ExcelDNA, so any assistance would be appreciated.

```
[ExcelFunction(Name = "multiplication", Description = "Multiply the two inputs")]
public static int testFunction(
    [ExcelArgument(Description = "the first number")] int baseNum, 
    [ExcelArgument(Description = "the second number")] int multiplier)
{
    return (baseNum * multiplier);
}
```

Function works as intended, however as mentioned before there is no description in Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special Excel-DNA IntelliSense extension that displays in-sheet descriptions for your function is not automatically part of your Excel-DNA add-in - you must either load it separately or do some more work to incorporate it in your add-in.

The best way to test the Excel-DNA IntelliSense extension is to download the pre-built `ExcelDna.IntelliSense(64).xll` add-ins from here (you have to figure out whether to use 32-bit or 64-bit, according to your Excel installation): https://github.com/Excel-DNA/IntelliSense/releases

Once you've downloaded it, and after your own add-in functions are working, you just File->Open the `ExcelDna.IntelliSense.xll` and the in-sheet IntelliSense should work fine.

If it still does not work after following these steps, the best support options are:

- Post more details to the public Google support group for Excel-DNA at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/exceldna
- Book an interactive support session with me via email and we can have a chat and a closer look over Skype.